# Oracle Designer 9i - Export layout information of ERD

Tags: oracle, migration, data-modeling, designer, erd

We have a repository of hundreds of Entity Relationship Diagrams with a specific layout and we have to migrate them to Oracle Data Modeler **including** layout information.

Actually we have to redraw all diagrams by hand in lack of an automatic import functionality including layout information.

Is there any possiblity to export layout information of Entity Relationship Diagrams in Oracle Designer 9i (via Database access or XML Export...)?

Thanks in advance,
Dominik

Answer (score 0):

Oracle data modeler provides tool to import ERDs from Oracle designer.
Please clarify term "specific layout" that you have used in "Entity Relationship Diagrams with a specific layout"